# Create Application like Panorama

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating application like panorama 360. Problem is how can i use the sensor accelerometer to capture continuous image and know about image is overlapping the 40% of the lastly capture image i have done lot many googling but nothing work for me can any body help me out . What should i do for this kind of problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...that is going to be difficult and it will probably require a pretty advanced algorithm to work properly.

I have no idea if something simple like this will work so take this with a grain of salt but how about cropping each image to something like 20x20 pixels. Change all the darkest pixels to black and all the lightest pixels to white. Then loop through all the pixels of the 2 images and compare if 40% of the pixels are equal to each other. And somehow stitch them together based on where the pixels were similar...

Comment: Thank for replay Edward. Do you have any idea about how i can use sensor to capture the continous image. How can i implement the solution that you have give

Comment: You will need to take pictures at predefined angles of holding the phone right? I'm sure you can find some info about how to do that like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261732/android-device-angle-to-vertical-axis